How can I make all my Swift Package Manager package optional like Firebase offers
I have a mono cocoapods repo, that host all our libraries. I'm in the process of adding support for Apple SPM. Everything is working on the package.swift configuration. But, I trying to have the same behavior as Firebase SPM package.
The behavior is when a someone want to add our packages, all the package are optional and with the "add to target" set to none in Xcode, to offer full control on what the user want to import (See image). Any idea on what am I missing ?
Firebase adding process
I've tried having target wrappers, a dummy empty package with no dependencies as the main product, but nothing seems to be working
Here's a obfuscated package.swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.9
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackages",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
      .library(
        name: "MyPackageA",
        targets: ["MyPackageA"]
      ),
      .library(
        name: "MyPackageB",
        targets: ["MyPackageB"]
      )
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
      .target(
        name: "MyPackageA",
        dependencies: ["MyCorePackageBinary", "MyPackageABinary"],
        path: "MyPackageAPath"
      ),
      .target(
        name: "MyPackageB",
        dependencies: ["MyCorePackageBinary", "MyPackageBBinary"],
        path: "MyPackageBPath"
      ),      
      .binaryTarget(
        name: "MyCorePackageBinary",
        path: "MyPath/MyCorePackageBinary.xcframework"
      ),
      .binaryTarget(
        name: "MyPackageABinary",
        path: "MyPathA/MyPackageABinary.xcframework"
      ),
      .binaryTarget(
        name: "MyPackageBBinary",
        path: "MyPathB/MyPackageBBinary.xcframework"
      )
    ]
)


How many products do you have in products: [...]? I think this is not something you can control. Xcode decides this on its own based on some factors. From what I can see, having multiple products automatically enables this behaviour. The same also happens if the project to which you are adding the package has multiple targets.

Related to @Sweeper's comment, Xcode changed it's behavior for Firebase across the different Xcode 15 minor release versions.

@Sweeper Like in my Package.swift example, I have 2 products, but they have automatically the iOS project already selected. For my testing, I use an empty swiftUI project, and add Firebase to check the result, and add my own, that have a different behaviour. I was curious, why.
